# Resolvent set of operator $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

> Let $X=C([0,1])$ and
>   $$
> X_1=\{f\in C^1([0,1])\colon f(0)=0\}\\
> X_2=\{f\in C^1([0,1])\colon f(0)=f(1)=0\}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> A_i\colon X_i\subset X\rightarrow X;\;\;\;A_if=f'
> $$
>   for $f\in D(A_i)$, where $i=1,2$;

I want to show that

1. The spectrum of $A_1$ is empty
2. The resolvent set of $A_2$ empty.

If we let $g\in X$ such that 
$$
(A_1-\lambda I))f=A_1f-\lambda f =g\;\;\;\;\;f(0)=0,
$$
then $R(\lambda,A_1)g=f(x)$ (the solution) exists for all $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$, hence the spectrum of $A_1$ is empty.

My question is about (2): How can I show that the resolvent set of $A_2$ is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \in C[0,1]$. Suppose $(A_2-\lambda I)f=g$ has a solution, where $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then
$$
         e^{-\lambda t}(f'-\lambda f)=e^{-\lambda t}g \\
              \frac{d}{dt}(e^{-\lambda t}f)=e^{-\lambda t}g \\
            0= e^{-\lambda t}f(t)|_{t=0}^{1}=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\lambda t}g(t)dt.
$$
So, it is not possible for $(L-\lambda I)$ to be surjective, which is easily seen by noting that there exists $g \in C[0,1]$ such that
$$
              \int_{0}^{1}e^{-\lambda t}g(t)dt \ne 0.
$$