# Find the resolvent set of a differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let $X=C[0,1]$ and define:
$$Af=f''\ \text{for }\ f \in D(A)=\{f\in C^{2}[0,1]: f(0)=f(1)=0 \}.$$
I want to find $\rho(A)$ that is the resolvent set of operator $A.$

I'm not sure how to proceed with this. From the definition $\rho(A)$ is the set of all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(A-zT)^{-1}$ is $1-1$ and onto.

My take on this problem is following. First I find the solutions to $Af-zf=f''-zf=0$ to get that $$f(t) = c_{1}e^{\sqrt{z}t}+c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{z}t}$$ solves the equation. Now by applying the boundary conditions I get that there is no $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the BC are satisfied and thus $\sigma(A)$ is empty and since $\rho(A) =\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(A) = \mathbb{C}.$  Is this correct?

Comment: $A$ acts from subspace $C^{2}[0,1] \subset C[0,1]$ into $C[0,1].$ If $f \in C[0,1] \setminus C^{2}[0,1]$ operator $A$ does not make sense and thus the definition. I follow the usual definition of the resolvent set and my approach was developed based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008302/resolvent-set-of-operator-a.

Comment: @BenW Just to be clear I used definition which can be found here http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/14SPRINGTEA/spectraltheory.pdf

Comment: You made a mistake when solving the differential equation. Your solution is valid only when $z >0$, but what about the case $z<0$? And more generally $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Michh Yes - my bad - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolvent $R(z)=(A-zI)^{-1}$ does not exist if $z=-n^2\pi^2$ where $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. This is because $\sin(n\pi x)$ vanishes at $0,1$ and
$$
       (A+n^2I)\sin(n\pi x) = 0,\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$

For $z \ne -n^2\pi^2$, the resolvent is determined by solving
$$
              f''+\lambda f=g,\;\;\; f(0)=f(1)=0.
$$
Variation of parameters can be used to solve this equation. The solution is
\begin{align}
     f(x)&=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(x-1))}{\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})}\int_{0}^{x}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}y)g(y)dy\\&+\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})}\int_{x}^{1}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(y-1))g(y)dy.
\end{align}

Comment: So $\rho(A)=\mathbb{C} \setminus \{-n^{2}\pi^{2}:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ right?

Comment: @data : NO. $\rho(A) = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{ -n^2\pi^2 : n=1,2,3,\cdots \}$. $0$ is in the resolvent set. The resolvent expression I gave you has a removable singularity at $\lambda=0$, and is equal to $(x-1)\int_0^x y g(y)dy + x\int_x^1 (y-1)g(y)dy$.

Comment: Yep - I use convention to exclude $0$ from $\mathbb{N}.$ Anyway thanks for your answer!

Comment: @data : oops, my blunder. Been rather I'll lately.

Answer (score 1):

It seems not correct.E.g.:The spectrum is not empty. Consider the function
$$f(t)=\sin(\pi t).$$
Then $$f^{''}(t)=-\pi^2\sin(\pi t)$$
thus $Af+\pi^2f=0$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for that comment!  Can you please comment on my general approach to this problem? Is there an alternative way to look at this problem?

Comment: I´m not yet sure. I´mthinking about that. By slightly generalizing the above example to $f_k(t)=\sin(k\pi t)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ You can see that the spectrum has at least countably many elements.